# send php mail connecting through smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to run this script to send an email

```
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();


$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = 'myaccount@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypass';
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;

$mail->SetFrom('myaccount@gmail.com', 'NAME SURNAME');

$mail->Subject    = 'FeedBack';

$mail->MsgHTML('hello');

$address = 'destination@gmail.com';
$mail->AddAddress($address);
$mail->Send();


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else {
  echo 'Message sent!';
}

?>
```

but it returns me these errors:

> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mydomain.com
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   CLIENT -> SERVER: 
>   Y29pbGx0ZWFuY2FwaXRhbGRldmVsb3BknfBnbWFpbC5jb20=
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   CLIENT -> SERVER: bmVgr2Vic2l0ZQ==
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14
>   Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14
>   Learn more at 534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754
>   n3sm29933619wja.36 - gsmtp
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   SMTP connect() failed.
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mydomain.com
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
>   Y29pbGx0ZWFuY2FwaXRhbvRldcVsb3BlckBnbWFpbC5jb20=
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: bmV3d2Vic2l0ZQ==
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14
>   Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.
>   534-5.7.14 Learn more at  534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754
>   y14sm29932162wjr.39 - gsmtp
>
> 2015-03-09 21:29:37   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-03-09 21:29:37  SMTP
>   connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

I can't understand why. If I run this script locally on wamp server it works but If upload it on the online server (linux) It doesn't work.

Comment: **Password command failed:**

Comment: password is right! If I run this script locally on wamp server it works but If upload it on the online server (linux) It doesn't work. just copy and paste!

Comment: This exact problem is covered [in the PHPMailer troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), and you're using an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Strange problem solved by removing `$mail->IsSMTP();`

Comment: well that means your just using mail() and the local mail server for sending, not gmail

Comment: and it may just be failing further upstream for the same reason.

Comment: but now by removing that line, am I doing things in the right way? or there could be some issues?

Comment: "right" ? your using the php mail function  not a direct socket to a smtp server, your also using a totally different mail server. is this right for you? that's your call.

Comment: I understand, but this can create problem to the application?

Comment: only you know how the application works and what it does so what method of php sending is suitable and what server is suitable.